# A-Frame coordinates for Leap Motion hands

Tags: three.js, aframe, leap-motion

I am trying to use [aframe-leap-hands](https://github.com/openleap/aframe-leap-hands) to interact with my aframe objects using the leap hands, but I'm having trouble accessing the hands' position and rotation relative to their parent camera. In the scene, I can see the hands moving and rotating, but when I try to print out the position and rotation on every tick, or inspect the scene console, it remains fixed at the default values.

I have also tried using the [leap documentation's](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/api/Leap.Hand.html#javaclasscom_1_1leapmotion_1_1leap_1_1_hand_1ac0a7c392bcdb3144d5170a36e3d08074) hand.palmPosition component that comes from the leap, but that seems to return the real-world coordinates relative to the leap sensor, and not the position in the aframe scene. I have the same problem with the rotation, except that I cannot find a way to read the current hand rotation in the leap documentation either.

What is the right way to go about getting the leap hands' position and rotation in an aframe scene?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit tricky... here's a [quick implementation](https://github.com/openleap/aframe-leap-hands/blob/4b6303afb962a95eff7c407ce2b84e66850bbf60/src/helpers/hand-body.js#L91-L96) that might help; I think it gets the position right, but not the rotation exactly.